# Refactor a functional interface

Tags: python

I have a functional interface to a backend library, which looks like this:

```
def func1(*pars, **kwargs):
    be = Backend(...)
    result = be.do_something(...)
    result = adapt(result)
    ...
    return result
```

The backend interface has changed a bit (a new `config` parameter is needed), so that now I need to refactor to something like:

```
def func1(config, *pars, **kwargs):
    be = Backend(config, ...)
    result = be.do_something(...)
    result = adapt(result)
    ...
    return result
```

I would need to change all functions in my interface to accept and pass this new `config` parameter. Do you have a better suggestion on how to proceed with this refactoring, so that:

- minimizes changes
- allows for easier future refactorings, where more parameters can be required by the backend

In general, do you have some pointers on how to provide clean functional interfaces in python?

Comment: Is `config` only used by `Backend`? Is the `Backend` dependent on the other parameters? If yes and no, inject the backend instead of the config.

Comment: @poke: That is a interesting idea, but I am reluctant to push the `Backend` dependency to an upper layer: my django layer is using the `interface`, which is *internally* using the `Backend`.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I think you're going to need to update each of your functions regardless, but you can do it in a way that will make future updates easier. Consider the following decorator:

```
def backend_wrapper(function):
    def _wrapper(arg1, arg2, arg3, *pargs, **kwargs):
        backend_args = (arg1, arg2, arg3)
        return function(backend_args, *pargs, **kwargs)
    return _wrapper
```

If you update all of your functions use this decorator and accept a new positional argument `backend_args`,  then you can apply all future updates to just the decorator.

```
class Backend:
    def __init__(self, *args):
        print 'Backend args: {}'.format(args)

@backend_wrapper
def func1(backend_args, *pargs, **kwargs):
    be = Backend(*backend_args)
    print 'Positional args: {}'.format(pargs)
    print 'Keyword args: {}'.format(kwargs)

func1('arg1', 'arg2', 'arg3', 'parg1', kwarg1='kwarg1')
# Backend args: ('arg1', 'arg2', 'arg3')
# Positional args: ('parg1',)
# Keyword args: {'kwarg1': 'kwarg1'}
```

So, now if we change the decorator to be:

```
def backend_wrapper(function):
    def _wrapper(arg1, *pargs, **kwargs):
        backend_args = (arg1,)
        return function(backend_args, *pargs, **kwargs)
    return _wrapper
```

Then, `func1` will still operate as intended.

```
func1('arg1', 'parg1', kwarg1='kwarg1')
# Backend args: ('arg1',)
# Positional args: ('parg1',)
# Keyword args: {'kwarg1': 'kwarg1'}
```

This issue here is that you're still going to need to update your function calls to pass in the new parameters as well. Unless you're able to make the `backend_args` global variables, I don't see a way around this. However, if this is the case, you can use something like:

```
class Backend:
    def __init__(self, *args):
        print 'Backend args: {}'.format(args)

def backendFactory(*backend_args):
    def _wrapper():
        return Backend(*backend_args)
    return _wrapper

def func1(*pargs, **kwargs):
    be = BackendFactory()
    print 'Positional args: {}'.format(pargs)
    print 'Keyword args: {}'.format(kwargs)

BackendFactory = backendFactory('arg1', 'arg2', 'arg3')
func1('parg1', kwarg1='kwarg1')
# Backend args: ('arg1', 'arg2', 'arg3')
# Positional args: ('parg1',)
# Keyword args: {'kwarg1': 'kwarg1'}
```

This creates a global variable `BackendFactory` that acts in a similar way to a class, except that it stores the instantiation variables. Note that this is messy and dangerous because it replies on you defining a global variable that is then used in your functions.